# What does it mean "a junkie's penis hunting" in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean " a junkie's penis hunting" in the following context?

> "I think usually when people think of a "real hormone", they mean
>   something that you can take out a vial of blood from whatever site is
>   most convenient to measure it, even if the nurse has to pull out **a
>   junkie's penis hunting** for a suitable vein."

By googling I found [this definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=penis%20hunting) but it seems that it doesn't have to do something with my context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just uses the literal meanings of *[junkie](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/junkie),* *[penis](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=penis)* and *[hunting](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hunt&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*.

You just need to know some information to have the context to understand it.

Drug junkies commonly develop [collapsed veins](http://luxury.rehabs.com/iv-drug-use/collapsed-veins/). These veins cannot be used for injections or for taking blood samples.

The sentence is just using the colorful image of a drug junkie who has damaged all the easily-accessible veins in his body, so a nurse taking a blood sample has to find ("hunt for") a vein in a more inconvenient location such as the penis.